# groupBy within withCount closure (Laravel 5.3.26)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, eloquent

Within Laravel 5.3.26, is it possible to group the result of `withCount` based on a column of that relationship? Something as follows, for example:

```
$brands = \App\Models\Brand::withCount([ 'products' => function ($query) {
        $query->groupBy('extra_attribute');
    } ])
    ->get();
```

This particular piece of code returns an empty collection.

Maybe I'm just not looking in the right places in the documentation or not googling properly, but I can't find anything about this particular scenario.

Could somebody point me into the right direction?

Thanks a bunch!

---

**Edit:** Currently I appear to have solved it with this:

```
$brands = \App\Models\Brand::with([ 'products' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('brand_id', 'extra_attribute')
        ->selectRaw('COUNT(*) AS products_count')
        ->groupBy('extra_attribute');
} ]);
```

and being able to fetch the total through something like `$brand->products->sum('products_count')`.

Feels extremely dirty, and probably is. Is this really the only way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `groupBy()` shouldn't be used in `withCount()` as `withCount()` is going to eager load the count of all items in the collection of `products` for each `Brand` grouped by `Brand` in the returned collection.  This would be equivalent to `$brand->products->count()` on a single `Brand`.

Between your 2 examples, the `groupBy()` is unnecessary if you aren't using this data elsewhere. If you are, it may be better to access your totals in the collections as:

```
//Controller
$brands = \App\Models\Brand::with('products')->get();

//View
@foreach($brands as $brand)
    <div>TOTAL PRODUCTS: {{ $brand->products->count() }}</div>
    @foreach($brand->products->groupBy('extra_attribute') as $attribute => $products)
        <div>TOTAL {{ $attribute }}: {{ $products->count() }}</div>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**--OR--**

You can have the best of both worlds and attach the count and the grouped relation by just doing both:

```
$brands = \App\Models\Brand::withCount('products')
    ->with(['products' => function ($query) {
        return $query->groupBy('extra_attribute');
    }])->get();
```

Then you can access the brand's `products_count` and grouped products:

```
$brands->each(function($brand) {
    $brand->products_count;
    $brand->products->each(function($products, $extra_attribute) {
        // Grouped Products
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Of course, you can pass a closure for withCount() too just like you do in with(), e.g as follows which gives visit count of `user_id 1` on `product_id 1`

```
User::where('id', 1)
->withCount(['visits'=> function($q) use ($product_id){
   $q->where('product_id', $product_id);
}])
```